# How to speak a language with a third declension adjective?

Tags: idiom, grammar-choice

Most Latin adjectives related to [names of countries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1328/79) and languages are of first and second declension: *Latinus*, *Graecus*, *Anglicus*…
If I want to express that I speak in any such language, I will simply use the derived adverb: *Latine/Graece/Anglice loquor.*

But how does it work if the adjective belongs to the third declension?
The list in the linked question contains, for example, *Islandiensis*, *Melitensis*, and *Thailandiensis*.
If I want to express speaking or otherwise using these languages, do I use the adverb normally?
Saying *Islandiensiter/Melitensiter/Thailandiensiter loquor* sounds weird.
I have never seen such adjectives in such use, so I have no intuition.
(I don't know whether the Romans ever had third declension adjectives together with *lingua*, so there may or may not be classical help.)

Is the *-iter* ending used under such circumstances?
Is a first and second declension alternative always used instead (*Islandice*, *Melitice* etc.)?
Or should I simply use the ablative like *lingua Melitensi loquor*?

This may be a hard question to answer, so answers based on experienced intuition are also welcome.
To decisively settle the matter, I imagine one would have to give examples of use, clear avoidance (where the adverb is used for first and second declension but not third), or using first and second declension alternatives for this purpose but third declension elsewhere.
I understand that is much to ask for, so I do not expect airtight proof.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, the *-ensiter* adverbs are not an option. As shown below, either a language actually has (or also has) a first/second declension adjective and one may use the corresponding adverb, or only a third declension one is possible, in which case one has to use the ablative with the noun *lingua*.

- Icelandic is *lingua Islandica*: the [Latin Wikipedia page](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_Islandica#cite_note-1) gives Conradus Gesnerus, *Mithridates: de differentiis linguarum* (1555) as a source. It can (not easily) be read [here](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=yTVUAAAAcAAJ&hl=it&pg=GBS.PP2). Ludovico Antonio Muratori speaks of *Islandica Lingua* in his *Antiquitates Italicae Medii Aevi* (1738-43), see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=mkFLAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1199&lpg=PA1199&dq=lingua+islandica&source=bl&ots=6rYlPgmtwg&sig=ACfU3U06xcYmLWKiBQeXaQSSrhBhshLtlw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOq9OA34viAhUgxcQBHe20DYM4ChDoATAHegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=lingua%20islandica&f=false).
  And here's what appears to be a lexicon of Icelandic (1959): *Lingua Islandica: Íslenzk tunga*:

  [image: Cover of Lingua Islandica]

  The adverb *Islandice* is also attested: see the front cover of a 17th century work (below) and the title of a 2009 book, *Clari Fabella: Islandice et Latine,* by Gustaf Cederschiöld, Samuel Cavallin.

  [image: Cover of Islandice et Latine]
- Maybe by analogy, being the only official and national language of *Thailandia*, Thai is often seen on Latin websites as *Lingua Thailandica*. For example, it's in Vicipaedia's [*Linguarum
  officialium
  catalogus*](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguarum_officialium_catalogus#Lingua_Thailandica). However that's pseudo-Latin at best, apparently absent in any official document. Instead, the [*Acta Apostolicae Sedis* (January 1983, Vol. LXXV, Pars I)](https://biblioteca.unisal.it/repository/Acta_Apostolicae_Sedis_075_1983_1_SL-10.4-D-2.w.pdf) reports the following:

  > Liturgia verbi expleta, Summus Pontifex, post audita verba dicta
  >   a Beatissimo Domino Antonio Petro Kòraiche, Patriarcha Antiocheno
  >   Maronitarum, ex noviter creatis primo, hanc allocutionem habuit, adhibita lingua : Italica, Gallica, Anglica, Hispanica, Germanica, Lusitana,
  >   **Thailandiensi**, Lettonica, Croata, Polonica [...]

  It seems clear that if "Thailandica" had been a possible choice, the editor would have used it. However, unlike *Islandice*, *Thailandiensiter* is not found by a Google verbatim search. Thus, apparently the way to go here is *lingua Thailandiensi loqui*.
- The same seems to be true for Maltese. The adjective is indeed *Melitensis* (not "*Meliticus/a/um*"), it can be found in Cicero's *In Verrem*, and did not change in modern times. [Mikiel Anton Vassalli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikiel_Anton_Vassalli) published a lexicon *Melitense-Latino-Italum* (it should've been *Latinum*, I think) in 1796:

  [image: Cover of the lexicon]

  Inside, the abbreviations "It." and "Lat." are used for *Italice* and *Latine*, but *Melitensiter* is nowhere to be found, and there are a couple of *in Melitensi sermone* that really seem to substitute the adverb. I believe this is enough evidence to conclude the ablative is necessary to "speak Maltese" too.
- For Chinese there is the problem of distinguishing the group of related language varieties, and what is commonly referred to, i.e. Standard Mandarin. The former appears to be described as *lingua(e) Sinica(e)*, the latter by *lingua Sinensis* - see [the Vicipaedia discussion](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disputatio:Lingua_Sinensis), but in practice there may be no difference. The [Latin Wikipedia page](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguae_Sinicae) references [*Lingua Sinica* by Petrus Ribadenaira, Philippus Alegambe, Nathaniel Sotvellus, Bibliotheca Scriptorum Societatis Iesu, vol. 2 (1676), p. 598](https://books.google.it/books?id=GKtLAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA598&q=%22lingua+sinica%22&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22lingua%20sinica%22&f=false). Besides that, Frédéric Guillaume Bergmann speaks of *lingua sinica* and *scriptura sinica* in his [De linguarum origine atque natura: dissertatio philosophica (1839)](https://books.google.it/books?id=yhpJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=lingua+sinica&source=bl&ots=eDLWa6iMqw&sig=ACfU3U1vJCk_AdcC3h1sYckJJ-dLrFqTSg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCvcnx9Y7iAhXOyqQKHbjRDaY4FBDoATAIegQIBxAB#v=snippet&q=sinica&f=false). On the other hand one has Martino Martini's *Grammatica Linguae Sinensis* (1651-1653), which deals with Mandarin specifically. At any rate, as was to be expected, *Sinensiter loqui* is [not](https://www.google.com/search?q=sinensiter&source=lnt&tbs=li:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP8ciE_47iAhUM6KQKHeIxD2sQpwUIJQ&biw=1440&bih=740) attested, whereas *Sinice loqui* [is](https://books.google.it/books?id=62l2miMFD-QC&pg=RA1-PA150&lpg=RA1-PA150&dq=sinice+loqui&source=bl&ots=KPCqstExhg&sig=ACfU3U3Su-Zov-fAwpoPdXZaFPUnUvGFoQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigr9HQ7Y7iAhWwPOwKHSVKDIAQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=snippet&q=sinice&f=false).
- Irish is *lingua Hibernica* (as seen in the title of the article "Noticulae De Lingua Hibernica", by Vernam Hull (1954)) and *Hibernice loqui* [is even attested](https://books.google.it/books?id=_YkJAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=hibernice+loqui&source=bl&ots=5d0l4twEVQ&sig=ACfU3U0RYog6fZsylPZ1UPk5NnwNR2cbdg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ3eLhg4_iAhWJCuwKHbLsAMoQ6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=hibernice%20loqui&f=false)
- Dutch is *lingua Nederlandica*, attested in [Humanistica Lovaniensia - Volume XLIII, Corona Martiniana](https://books.google.it/books?id=q--UDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA476&lpg=PA476&dq=lingua+nederlandica&source=bl&ots=Soffe_zLl6&sig=ACfU3U0JXmvmAe-D28NLKL-KSeSvDsqiaQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyzL66hI_iAhXBaFAKHTL8CIUQ6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=lingua%20nederlandica&f=false). This is also the expression used by [the Belgian *Schola Nova*](http://www.scholanova.be/index.php/la/admissio#fn4). And indeed, the adverb is present e.g. in de Groot's [*Lineamenta theologiae christianae universae*](https://books.google.it/books?id=IT0-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=nederlandice+loqui&source=bl&ots=V8HRB38x4P&sig=ACfU3U0wy2La9wCbB5dV3nuWPM966TQG0g&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ2Y2ziI_iAhUfwAIHHf3QA8oQ6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=nederlandice&f=false).

Comment: Many thanks! This is a very convincing and thorough answer. Regarding *Melitense-Latino-Italum*: In compound adjectives only the last part is inflected. You could have a *Lexicon Anglico-Latino-Anglicum*, for example. What surprises me is that it isn't *Melitensi-*, but I don't know how regular these compound formations are in Latin.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Ah I see! Indeed, not being familiar with any such lexicon, the _Melitense_ had led me to think they were all supposed to be neuter nominatives. Anyway I think you're right in doubting the regularity of such formations, at least in non-contemporary works.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of using an adverbial form of a nation or an ethnicity to refer to its language and speaking in it. Usually, it is:

> "*Linguā Latinā loquī*"
> to speak by means of the Latin language...

as in the ablative adjectival phrase.

In your case,

> Iceland = *Islandia*, and Icelandic= *Islandiēnsis*; 
>   Malta = *Melitae*, and Maltese = Melitensis;
>  
>   and Thailand = *Thailandia*, and Thai = *Thailandiēnsis*<sup>1</sup>

Therefore (assuming these adjectives are I-stem):

> *Linguā Islandiēnsī loquī* = to speak (by means of/in the) Icelandic (language)
> *Linguā Melitensī loquī* = to speak (by means of/in the) Maltese (language)
> *Linguā Thailandiēnsī loquī* = to speak (by means of/in the) Thai (language).

1. Joonas Ilmavirta, response Aug 6, 2016 to "What are the Latin names for modern countries?" by Sam K, Aug 6, 2016, (accessed May 6, 2019), https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1330/4731; "List of Latin names of countries," *Wikipedia*, last edited May 6, 2019, (accessed May 6, 2019), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_names_of_countries.

Comment: Using *lingua* and an ablative is indeed an option as I mentioned in the question, but using the adverb is indeed common. In my experience the typical way to "speak Latin" is to *Latine loqui*, not *lingua Latina loqui* (which I'd regard more as "to speak in the Latin language"). The question was whether the same option is available for the third declension.

Comment: @ Joonas Ilmavirta♦: in that case, it would be *islandiensē loquī* (and so on), wouldn't it? Personally, though, I prefer the ablative "*linguā*" use, because it is more specific.

Comment: But the adverb corresponding to a third declension adjective does not end in *-e*. It ends in *-iter*. I have seen the adverbs in *-e* with languages numerous times, but I don't recall seeing third declension languages ever used. The expected analogous expression is *Islandiensiter loqui*, and the question was whether this is valid. Any examples of its use or clear avoidance (using *lingua* where second declension languages use the adverb) would settle the matter.