# What is the -ē form in “Latīnē loquor”?

Tags: declension, word-formation

To say you speak in Latin or in Greek, you say “Latīne” or “Graecē”. What is that *-ē* form? I cannot figure it out from any declension table I am aware of.

Does the same -ē ending work for any other language, or is it only a set form for some languages? E.g. can you say “Francogallicē” or “Japonicē”, or do you need to use some standard case & declension (ablative maybe)?

Comment: See [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/466/what-did-romans-call-their-language/469#469): "Instead, the adverbial form was preferred: *latine loquor*..."

Comment: Related: [How to speak a language with a third declension adjective?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6631)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the adverbial ending. To convert a first/second adjective to an adverb, you replace the declension ending with *-ē*: if a document is hard to understand, it's *obscūra* (or *obscūrus* etc), but if I do something in a way that's hard to understand, it's *obscūr**ē***.

For third adjectives, *-iter* is more common: a *celer* person acts *celer**iter***.

Comment: @Florianus The adverbial ending is used in some other contexts, and I usually interpret it to mean "in Latin". For instance, Kurt and Barbara Aland's edition of the New Testament, *Novum Testamentum Latine*.