# How would you express "Russian bear" in Linnaeus species terminology?

Tags: scientific-names

I was trying to express "Russian bear" in scientific terms.

*Ursus* would be the bear part of it.  But I really couldn't figure out how to express Russia.

[List of mammals of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mammals_of_Russia) gave me no hints.

I did see terms alluding to Siberia, as in *sibirica*.  Canada - *canadensis*.  *Ursus americanus*, etc...  So terms that would not have known in Latin times have been "Latinized".  I recognized nothing similar for Russia.

*Rus* or something like it would be my expectation and there were a number of names ending with it.  *Myospalax psilurus*, *Phodopus sungorus*, *Microtus obscurus*... but I got the impression that these were more regular Latin word-ending syllables than denoting Russian-ess.

I also looked around for questions about "Russia" here.  Nothing looked it answered the question.  Google Translate left it at "Russian ursus".

Comment: You can see the Latin word for Russian and other countries [in this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1328/what-are-the-latin-names-for-modern-countries/1330#1330).

Comment: Ursus Rusicus then?  Ursus Russia is kinda jarring as it *looks* half Latin half English.  Or Ursus Russi, but that needs that special accented character to work.

Comment: So, Russia is the country, Russicus is the adjective, and Russi are the people. *Ursus russicus* is right. You don't actually need the macron either. They're there to show pronunciation in Classical Latin.

Comment: Note there is an extinct species of bears called [*Ursus rossicus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursus_rossicus).

Comment: The word for “Russian” in mediaeval and modern Latin is russicus. I do not see anything wrong with “ursus russicus”.