# Free online resources/established books for learning Latin?

Tags: resource-request

I'm looking for something like Duolingo, but for Latin. (By the way, it is a bit upsetting that hardly any of these sites include Latin as a learnable language; although I suspect that it is because the teaching methods of these sites rely heavily on the spoken word.)

I'd be very happy if any of these sites are up to snuff and not obscure, vocabulary sort of resources.

As for the books, they needn't be free, but good, established books for learning Latin.

I am almost exclusively interested in the written form, and not the spoken version. This is to aid in my reading of philosophy.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you seen [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/957/79) for self-study material for Latin? If you think your inquiry is answered by that one, we can mark this as duplicate to make it easier to find. If not, please specify how this is different. The linked question also contains a banner about resource requests; please read it. Our policy is that broad resource requests should be proposed on [meta](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/79) before asking, but sufficiently narrow requests are fine without such formalities.

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate of another one, but it can be reopened if edited. I hope the linked question gives you what you need!