# Self-teaching: Good resource for learning subjunctive

Tags: classical-latin, resource-request, mood

I am self-teaching Latin and have no instructors to whom I can ask questions. I am at a loss for learning subjunctive (mostly its uses and translating into English) and would like a resource that handles teaching subjunctive particularly well (even if it is less good at teaching other aspects of Latin). I am currently working systematically through *Latin: An Intensive Course* by Moreland and Fleischer. There is no answer key included with the book, and I have found several mistakes in ones that have been posted online.

Comment: Welcome to the site! We actually have a [general self-study question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/957/79), so I think it's better if this one focuses on just the subjunctive.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks for the link! I’ve edited my question so it focuses on just the subjunctive.

Comment: If you'd like to, I could explain the subjunctive to you along with some lecture notes I have.

Comment: @Stallmp That would be great!

Comment: Alright, would you like me to explain it here, or in another 'medium'? So that I can answer your questions as well. What way do you prefer?

Comment: @Stallmp If you are able to make a chat room, I think I that would work well for this since it would be separate from this post, but others could look at it if they feel it would be useful to them.

Comment: This is the link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91785/latin-subjunctive

Answer (score 1):

This may unfortunately be something of a non-answer, but please bear with me.
The Latin conjunctive or subjunctive (one thing, two names) is a little tricky and can easily be confusing.
I actually imagine you made this very observation and asked the question for that very reason.

There might be good sources out there that explain how it works, but I am not sure if any source will be clear enough.
Instead, I recommend taking a look at several different sources.
Different focuses, points of view, analogies, and examples help you get a more multi-faceted view to the matter.
An excellent way to get explanations to tricky properties of the subjunctive is to ask (focused) questions on this site.
We can help you put things in context and explain why things work as they do.
But this site alone will not suffice; we probably won't answer requests like "please explain what the subjunctive is and how it's used", so you need to get the basics elsewhere.
But when you work your way through texts and examples, I am sure questions will arise, and those we will be happy to help you with.

I hope someone has actual resources to suggest for learning the subjunctive.
There are some good Latin grammars out there, but I guess their approach isn't that good a fit for someone learning something for the first time.