# How to start learning Latin?

Tags: resource-request, study-strategies

I am a newbie to this language so I don't know where to start. I am ready to take a lot of effort and would really like to know how to master this language. How can I get started with learning Latin?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you taken a look at [our question about learning Latin on one's own](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/957/79)? Do you think that contains what you were after, or do you specifically want answers on how to start serious study from scratch? I'm just trying to figure out whether this should be regarded as a duplicate of the old question (in which case we'd link the two together) or a separate question with a focus on getting started.

Comment: I would specifically like some answers on how to get serious study from scratch .In fact I am learning French and since many words have Latin roots I want to learn it as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest a bit of background reading before you take the plunge. 'A Natural History of Latin' by Tore Jansen would be a good place to start: it is  an excellent survey of Latin and its history, demonstrating very gently how to approach it while introducing the accidence and syntax in a general, but very positive, way. If nothing else gives you an appetite for Latin, this certainly will.

Good luck. Latin repays all the effort you can put into it!