# My name is Jan., introduction

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Which of these two sentences is correct?

a) *Mi nomen est Jan.*

b) *Mi nomen Jan est.*

The word order of a Latin sentence is SOV, but I have found a) online, which is SVO.

Thank you.

Comment: similar but not identical: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16036/why-is-it-nomen-mihi-est-for-my-name-is-but-its-tibi-nomen-est-for-your

Comment: Related: [What word order resolves the ambiguity of two nominative nouns in a sentence?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/669)

Comment: Do you mean mihi?

Comment: SVO/SOV isn't actually relevant here because *Jan* isn't an object, but a predicate nominative.

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct. Latin allows both word orders. The idea that Latin strictly and in every sentence follows Subject-Object-Verb word order is wrong; on the contrary, word order in Latin is relatively free and is used as a stylistic device, to stress individual words, and so on.

To say one's name, it is indeed common to use the possessive dative, as you have, although the form *mi* is rather rare in prose, and you are far more likely to see *mihi*. The name itself is often given in the nominative or the dative.

The Roman author and hobby linguist A. Gellius wrote a short piece on saying one's name, ([*Noctes Atticae*, 15,29](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1254/1/0#335)) where he says:

> Duae istae in loquendo figurae notae satis usitataeque sunt: "mihi nomen est Iulius" et "mihi nomen est Iulio"
>
> These two figures of speech are well-known and common enough: *mihi nomen est Iulius* and *mihi nomen est Iulio*

(He then goes on to describe a third option, using the name adjectively in agreement with *nomen*, which, however, seemed even to Gellius, a native speaker in the classical era, strange and noteworthy, so it would hardly appear sensible to emulate it.)

In your case it makes no difference, as *Jan* is presumably not declined. However, you could Latinize your name as Ioannes (or Joannes; a famous pope from the last century [preferred that spelling](https://medium.com/in-medias-res/theres-no-j-in-latin-your-holiness-5a331c3f7a06)), in that case you could say:

- Mihi nomen est Ioannes.
- Mihi nomen est Ioanni.

A. Gellius does not mention the option of using the genetive, but it is also attested.

As I said, you are not bound to this particular word order. For example, in Plautus we find:

- nomen Mercurio est mihi (Amphitruo, Prologue)
- nomen Arcturo est mihi (Rudens, Prologue)

but also:

- mihi est Menaechmo nomen (Menaechmi 6,9)

and also, to add some indirect speech to the mix:

> ceterum quantum lubet me poscitote aurum: ego dabo.
> quid mihi refert Chrysalo esse nomen, nisi factis probo?
>
> aside from that, ask as much gold of me as you like: I shall give it to you.
> What use its it that my name is Chrysalus [from Greek χρυσός = gold] if I do not show it in my actions?

You can use any of these examples as a model (remarkably *none* of them has SOV word order, although that wouldn't be wrong either, e.g.: *Nomina his Lucumo atque Arruns fuerunt*, Livius: Ab urbe condita 1,34). The intuition which word order is possible and which works best in a given situation requires a lot of reading (personally I feel I have not nearly read enough to feel sure about it at all times). However, in a simple sentence like this, you have a lot of freedom.

Comment: I completely rewrote this answer to focus on the phrase in question, not abstract considerations of word order.

Comment: When you say "using the genitive' do you mean a possessive pronoun?

Comment: @TKR no, I mean something like *Mihi nomen est Iulii.*

Comment: Do you have an example of that usage? I'm surprised it's possible.

Comment: @TKR The genitive is very rare in this usage but is sometimes attested: e.g. (...) _fuit interim effugium legionibus in castra quibus **Veterum** nomen est_. Tac. _Hist._ 4.18.3 (‘ and so the legions meanwhile were able to escape to the camp that was called Vetera.’). Cf. also Bassols de Climent's (1956: 68) _Sintaxis latina_: "En el giro _mihi nomen est_ se puede expresar el nombre propio en nominativo (_Antonius_) o en genitivo (_Antonii_) o en dativo (_Antonio_)". However, your intuition is correct: the genitive _Antonii_ is indeed very rare (if not impossible!) in the Classical period.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel By the way, I've realized that in your posts you typically write "genetive" instead of "genitive". Is the former form also accepted in English or is this just a preference of yours?

Comment: @Mitomino Are we sure that the camp was not called *castra Veterum* (i.e. the genitive is part of the name)? It's hard to see where a genitive would come from in this construction.

Comment: @TKR This example is also given by Pinkster (2015: 1272) in parallel with the similar contrast between _Gelasimo nomen mi indidit parvo pater_ (Pl. _St._ 174) and _Q. Metellus praetor, cui ex virtute **Macedonici** nomen inditum erat_ (Vell. 1.11.2).

Comment: @Mitomino Thanks, I'd never encountered that usage before. (I can't see your Google Books link unfortunately.)

Comment: @Mitomino Hm, I thought dictionaries would at least support "genetive" as an alternative spelling, but at least Merriam-Webster does not appear to do so. It is mostly a personal idiosyncrasy. I also prefer, in the context of studying Latin at least, the spelling "condicional."