# Learning from scratch

Tags: classical-latin, new-latin, study-strategies

I am interested in learning Latin. I have tried to find good resources to do this online but have found a great deal of noise. Does anyone have any good recommendations of how to properly learn Latin from scratch? Books or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I recommend looking at [this post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/957/how-can-i-study-latin-on-my-own) for learning resources

Comment: Welcome! I second the comment by @Adam. Please check that other question out. If you don't find what you were looking for, please edit this question to specify what you would like. I think that one should have what you need, but you need to judge it yourself. We can make a permanent link from this post to the other so that anyone who finds your question finds the resource list.

Comment: @Adam Thank you I will give it a read. So far it seems like it was just what I was looking for. Cheers.