# Translating "a forest's son" to Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

everyone. I'm trying to translate the phrase "a forest's son" from song lyrics into Latin. I would like to say "son of the forest." My background is a little bit of Ecclesiastical Latin from singing in choirs.

From Google Translate, I received a translation of "filius silvam." I asked a friend of mine who knows Latin a bit better, and he was unsure if it should read "filius de silvam."

How would I correctly say "son of the forest"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately neither suggested translation is correct.
In Latin *de* is a preposition meaning "(down) from", although similar words are used to express the genitive in Romance languages.

What you need is the nominative of the son (*filius* is the nominative) and genitive of the forest (the genitive of *silva* is *silvae*).
So the translation should be ***filius silvae***.

As pointed out in a comment, one option is to use an adjective instead of a genitive.
Latin has the adjective *silvestris*, "related to forest".
Therefore you have the alternative ***filius silvestris***.
This could mean a son that likes spending time in forests or who grew up in one.
The genitive is the way to go when the possession is more concrete.
If a specific forest is somehow to be considered the father, then *filius silvae* is definitely the way to go.

As usual, context matters a lot.
Fortunately *filius silvae* is a good general translation.

Comment: That makes sense. It's like "et de profundo lacu" from Fauré's requiem. Excellent, thank you so much. Do you recommend any texts on Latin language/grammar? I have an intermediate understanding of a few Romance languages, so difficulty isn't too much of a concern. I would prefer sometime mainly in English, however.

Comment: @SprNtndoChlmrs I'm glad to have been able to help! [This question about self learning material](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/957/79) is a good place to start looking; it gives far better suggestions than I could in a comment. If you are looking for a good book for your specific case and those general ones seem to miss the point, you can ask a focused separate question.

Comment: I wonder if *filius silvestris* might also work?

Comment: @DerÜbermensch It would but with a somewhat different meaning. I added a discussion on that. Good suggestion!