# Latin translation for the following English words

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm inspired to start learning Latin, and to mark this event, I'm trying to determine what the Classical Latin are for the following words. I appreciate, just like ancient Greek, there may be variations - so maybe I can say Roman Latin to be the same as Classical Latin.

1. beginning (point from which anything begins) - initium
2. begin - incipere
3. from the beginning (beginning, as part of a whole) - principium
4. a beginning (a beginning in learning something new)
5. history of humanity
6. ancient history - antiqua historia
7. History (as in: this is history) - hoc est historia
8. ancient - antiqua - antiquitus (ancient times)

I've tried various online translators and Google searches, but not being proficient in either, I can't be absolutely sure if what I have found is correct. Also, it's also been suggested to me to check *Riddle and Arnold's copious and critical English to Latin dictionary*.

I appreciate Latin can be complex (for me) with tenses and so on, so I just want to push the boat out and start with these inspired words.

Comment: Welcome to studying Latin – a good place to start might be to invest in a dictionary! This website would be a good place to ask if you struggle to interpret what it tells you or you're interested in the specific nuances of the different words.

Comment: Welcome! I agree with @dbmag9 that having a good Latin dictionary will be helpful. We also happen to have a great community wiki question with answers on [which Latin dictionary you should use](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why). There's also another question to help you find [Latin self-study tools](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/957/how-can-i-study-latin-on-my-own).

Comment: @Adam - many thanks Adam. I have just completed a book digitisation project of a PHD thesis on William Salesbury (1520), and I got the chance to learn about the roots of many Welsh words, most Latin, so I can apply my learning approach to languages and not worry too much about pronunciation. There's a great Patreon account I've signed up to as well, with seriously extensive learning resources, and your suggestions are as equally valuable to me. I'm basic/proficient in Italian, which helps of course.