# What is the preferred beginners book on beginning to learn latin?

Tags: classical-latin

This is for someone who wants to begin studying but has little to no knowledge of the language. Should I stick to a classic Latin primer or something more modern? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question sounds like a duplicate of [how can I study Latin on my own](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/957/how-can-i-study-latin-on-my-own) which includes different book series in each answer. If you're looking for something a bit more specific let us know, though!

Comment: It seems to me that what you are looking for can be found in the question that @Adam links to, so we have marked this as a duplicate. If you don't find what you are looking for, please edit your question (using the "edit" button under it) to describe in more detail what you would like to have and how the resources listed in the linked question fall short of that. In that case this question can be reopened. // Also: Welcome to the site! If you have any questions while you're learning Latin, I hope you ask some of them here on our site.